# How to find months between the given date range in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

The inputs that I would get for my stored procedure are the start and end dates, so based on these dates I need the months between the date range and also the start and end dates of those months.

**Example:**

```
@StartDate  DATETIME = '20161125', @EndDate    DATETIME = '20170220';

@StartDate  DATETIME = '20161125',   
@EndDate    DATETIME = '20170220';
```

What I essentially need to create is a CTE or a temp table with these results:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post expected results and actual results as text and not as images,since images might be blocked in some domains and it will be harder to get data for testing..

Comment: Please check this link  to know more on how to improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What will you use these results for? If used in comparisons with other data, be aware that, if that other data contains time components, a range such as `20161125` to `20161130` will *exclude* any data that occurred *after midnight* during 30th November.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i use these ranges for an internal calculation which is not going to be affected if any data after midnight of the end date is excluded, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following query

```
declare @StartDate  date = '20161125', @EndDate    date = '20170220';

with cte as (
    select startDate = @StartDate,
           endDate = @EndDate,
           month=format(@StartDate,'MMM-yy'),  
           monthStart=@StartDate , 
           monthEnd =EOMONTH(@StartDate,0)
    union all
    select  @StartDate, 
            @EndDate,
            format(dateadd(day,1,monthEnd),'MMM-yy'),
            dateadd(day,1,monthEnd),
            iif(eomonth(dateadd(day,1,monthEnd),0)>@EndDate,
                  @EndDate,eomonth(dateadd(day,1,monthEnd),0))
    from cte
    where monthEnd<@EndDate
)
select * from cte
```

**Note that : function `EOMONTH` can be used from sql-server 2012 and above**

**EDIT** version without using `iif` or `format` or `eomonth` functions

```
declare @StartDate  datetime = '20161125', 
        @EndDate    datetime = '20170220';

with cte as (
    select startDate = @StartDate,
           endDate = @EndDate,
           month=Left(DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate),3) + '-' + Right(DATENAME(YEAR, @StartDate),2),  
           monthStart=@StartDate , 
           monthEnd =dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@StartDate)+1,0)-1
    union all
    select  @StartDate, 
            @EndDate,
            Left(DATENAME(MONTH, dateadd(day,1,monthEnd)),3) + '-' + Right(DATENAME(YEAR, dateadd(day,1,monthEnd)),2),
            dateadd(day,1,monthEnd),
            case when  dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(day,1,monthEnd))+1,0)-1 > @EndDate 
                 then @EndDate 
                 else dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(day,1,monthEnd))+1,0)-1 end
    from cte
    where monthEnd<@EndDate
)
select * from cte
```

here the output

```
startDate   endDate month   monthStart  monthEnd
2016-11-25  2017-02-20  Nov-16  2016-11-25  2016-11-30
2016-11-25  2017-02-20  Dec-16  2016-12-01  2016-12-31
2016-11-25  2017-02-20  Jan-17  2017-01-01  2017-01-31
2016-11-25  2017-02-20  Feb-17  2017-02-01  2017-02-20
```

hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but i'am using sql-server 2008 r2, any replacement for EOMONTH function, please suggest.

Comment: yes you can use this `dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@date)+1,0)-1` instead

Comment: can you please replace the alternative for EOMONTH in your above script and paste the complete script back? getting syntax errors when iam doing it, there might be something that i' am doing wrong.

Comment: @ArK you can check the updated answer now and mark it as answer if it helped you and upvote please

Comment: this exactly what i wanted, thanks very much for the help, upvoted and accepted.